# SVG with border or padding style is cropped when apply on image element

Tags: javascript, html, svg

```js
const svgStr = document.querySelector("svg").outerHTML,
        svgBlob = new Blob([svgStr], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" }),
            imgElem = new Image();
        imgElem.src = URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
        document.body.appendChild(imgElem);
```

```html
<div>inline svg</div>
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
             style="border:5px solid red;">
        </svg>
<br>  <br>      
<div>svg as image content</div>
```

I try to convert svg string  to image element. It has 5px border.
when I add this svg in inline html, svg don't crop but
when I try to load svg as image then svg crop.
It is only visible when scale down, apply ( `transform:scale(0.9)`).

I try to adjust svg width, height and viewbox but failed.

Then I try to set height and width on image element

```js
imgElem.width = 310;
imgElem.height = 310;
```

But again,no success.

Output image:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

How to fix this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Then as a solution - use outline and its offset to put graphics inside  svg instead of real border.

outline:5px solid #F008;
outline-offset:-5px;

Disadvantages - may cover some svg content and if there is need of "pushing" contents away from outline drawnings then svg viewBox params should be edited. (added green ring for demo)

```js
const svgStr = document.querySelector("svg").outerHTML,
        svgBlob = new Blob([svgStr], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" }),
            imgElem = new Image();
        imgElem.src = URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
        document.body.appendChild(imgElem);
```

```html
<div>inline svg</div>
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
             style="outline:5px solid #F008;outline-offset:-5px;">
   <g stroke="green" fill="white" stroke-width="2">
     <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="148"/>
   </g>
        </svg>
<br>  <br>      
<div>svg as image content</div>
```

Comment: Default value of `object-fit` is fill. Real issue in image-parser.  CSS doesn't work here.
I attached code snippet